# Как сделать так, чтобы контент занимал всю высоту секции?

Tags: html, css, swiper

Я использовал Swiper JS для слайда целых полноэкранных секций, но столкнулся с проблемой: содержимое в Swiper не хочет растягиваться на всю высоту секции, так как у меня для section стоит правило padding: 80px 0, можно было бы убрать это правило, но тогда все будет выглядеть не так как мне нужно . Как сделать так, чтобы слайдер растягивался на всю высоту секции .services и контент при этом никуда не уплывал.
PS я сделал фон зеленым специально, чтобы было видны отступы и чтобы перейти к следующему слайду надо нажать "Узнать подробнее"

Сам сайт ca50234.tmweb.ru

Весь код jsfiddle.net/u3vp4rto/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.services {
    background-color: green;
}


.services .swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.services .swiper-wrapper {
    padding: -80px 0 !important;
}

/*first-slider*/

.services-first-slider {
    background: url(../img/services-bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: right;
    position: relative;
}


.services-bg {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.sidebar {
    max-width: 617px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #090F14;
    margin-left: -120px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding-top: 120px;
    z-index: 99;
}


.sidebar h3 {
    padding-left: 120px;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}


.sidebar-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 120px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none !important;
}


.sidebar-menu li {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


.sidebar-menu li a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #777777;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.sidebar-menu li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}


.big {
    transform: scale(1.5) translateX(16.5%);
    color: #fff;
}


.sidebar-menu li.big a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


.sidebar-nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 120px;
}


.sidebar-nav li {
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.actived {
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.services-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 1.5;
    position: relative;
}


.services-info .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 664px;
    width: 100%;
}


.services-info-title {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 400;
}


.services-info p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}


.services-first-slider .wrapper .content {
    display: flex;
}


.services-info-title {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}


.services-info-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}


.services-info-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}


.services-info-footer a.order:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}


.services-info-footer a.order {
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Thai', sans-serif;
}


.services-info-footer .details {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Thai', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.services-info-footer .details:hover {
    font-size: 26px;
}


.invisible {
    display: none;
}

.visible {
    display: block;
}


/*second slider*/

.services-second-slider,
.services-third-slider {
    background: url(../img/services-bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: left;
    color: #fff;
}


.services-second-slider .wrapper .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


.services-second-slider .title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 52px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120px;
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    margin-bottom: 180px;
}


.services-second-slider .big-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.services-second-slider .block {
    width: 50%;
}


.services-second-slider .desc.block .text {
    font-size: 18px;
    max-width: 577px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    margin-bottom: 143px;
}


.services-second-slider .order {
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Thai', sans-serif;
}


.services-second-slider .order:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}


.services-second-slider .advantages h4 {
    font-size: 27px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}


.services-second-slider .advantages {
    margin-top: -100px;
}


.services-second-slider .adv-show-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.wallet,
.team {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}


.wallet img,
.accessible img,
.team img,
.fast img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.services-second-slider .first-block span,
.services-second-slider .second-block span {
    max-width: 319px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1.3;
}


.wallet,
.accessible,
.team,
.fast {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


.services-second-slider .second-block {
    margin-right: 100px;
}


.services-second-slider .footer-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.services-second-slider .back,
.services-second-slider .work-expl {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Thai', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}


.services-second-slider span.text-back,
.services-second-slider span.text-next {
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.back:hover span.text-back {
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


.work-expl:hover span.text-next {
    font-size: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


.services-second-slider .arrow {
    font-size: 30px;
}


.services-second-slider .arrow.left {
    margin-right: 20px;
}


.services-second-slider .arrow.right {
    margin-left: 20px;
}


/*third slider*/

.services-third-slider .wrapper .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.services-third-slider .title {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 120px;
}


.services-third-slider .swiper-container {
    width: 890px;
}


.sequence {
    background-color: red;
}


.services-third-slider .back {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans Thai', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.services-third-slider .back:hover .services-third-slider .arrow.left {
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services" id="services">
        <div class="swiper-container services-slider">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide services-first-slider">
                    <div class="services-bg">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="sidebar">
                                    <h3>Наши услуги</h3>
                                    <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                                        <li id="business-card"><a href="#">Сайт-визитка</a></li>
                                        <li id="landing"><a href="#">Landing page</a></li>
                                        <li id="market"><a href="#">Интернет-магазин</a></li>
                                        <li id="corp"><a href="#">Корпоративный сайт</a></li>
                                        <li id="bitrix"><a href="#">1C Битрикс</a></li>
                                        <li id="advertising"><a href="#">Контекстная реклама</a></li>
                                        <li id="seo"><a href="#">SEO оптимизация</a></li>
                                        <li id="promotion"><a href="#">Продвижение в соц. сетях</a></li>
                                        <li id="marketing"><a href="#">Контент-маркетинг</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                        <li></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="services-info">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="business-card">Сайт-визитка</div>
                                        <div class="landing invisible">Landing page</div>
                                        <div class="market invisible">
                                            <div class="services-info-title">
                                                Созданные экспертами «Inter-web» сайты интернет-магазинов имеют функциональность, необходимую для успешной онлайн-торговли.
                                            </div>
                                            <p>Что входит в нашу работу:</p>
                                            <div class="services-info-block">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>+ Подготовка технического задания</li>
                                                    <li>+ Разработка прототипа</li>
                                                    <li>+ Верстка макета</li>
                                                    <li>+ Интеграция дизайна</li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>+ Написание уникальных текстов</li>
                                                    <li>+ Сбор семантики</li>
                                                    <li>+ Тестирование и запуск</li>
                                                    <li>+ Подключение веб-аналитики</li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="services-info-footer">
                                                <a class="order" href="#">Сделать заказ</a>
                                                <a href="#" class="details next">Узнать подробнее &rarr;</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="corp invisible">Корпоративный сайт</div>
                                        <div class="bitrix invisible">1C Битрикс</div>
                                        <div class="advertising invisible">Контекстная реклама</div>
                                        <div class="seo invisible">SEO оптимизация</div>
                                        <div class="promotion invisible">Продвижение в соц. сетях</div>
                                        <div class="marketing invisible">Контент-маркетинг</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide services-second-slider">
                    <div class="services-bg">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="title">Интернет-магазин под ключ</div>
                                <div class="big-block">
                                    <div class="desc block">
                                        <div class="text">
                                            Интернет-магазин – прекрасный способ организовать эффективные продажи через интернет. Функционал сайта регулярно дорабатывается и совершенствуется. Бизнес, основная цель которого, получение прибыли путём продажи товаров и услуг, нуждается в качественной работе профессионалов.
                                        </div>
                                        <a class="order" href="#">Сделать заказ</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="advantages block">
                                        <h4>Преимущества использования Интернет-магазина</h4>
                                        <div class="adv-show-block ">
                                            <div class="first-block">
                                                <div class="wallet">
                                                    <img src="img/wallet.svg" alt="wallet">
                                                    <span>Для поддержания работы интернет-магазина требуется только оплата домена и хостинга</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="accessible">
                                                    <img src="img/accessible.svg" alt="accessible">
                                                    <span>Ваш магазин будет доступен покупателем 24 часа в сутки – 7 дней в неделю</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="second-block">
                                                <div class="team">
                                                    <img src="img/team.svg" alt="team">
                                                    <span>Владелец интернет-магазина получает доступ к огромной аудитории</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="fast">
                                                    <img src="img/fast.svg" alt="fast">
                                                    <span>Команда хороших исполнителей способна запустить работающий онлайн-магазин за короткий срок</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="footer-block">
                                    <a href="#" class="back"><span class="arrow left">&larr;</span>
                                        <span class="text-back">Вернуться назад</span></a>
                                    <a href="#" class="work-expl next"><span class="text-next">Примеры работ</span><span class="arrow right">&rarr;</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide services-third-slider">
                    <div class="services-bg">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="title">Примеры работ</div>
                                <div class="swiper-container example-gal">
                                    <div class=" swiper-wrapper">
                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                            <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="example">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                            <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="example">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                            <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="example">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                                            <img src="img/example.jpg" alt="example">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                                    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="footer-block">
                                    <a href="#" class="back"><span class="arrow left">&larr;</span>
                                        <span class="text-back">Вернуться назад</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

В css добавь `box-sizing: border-box;` - ограничение по границе

Или вот: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: а куда именно добавлять? Я просто попробовал вписать это в секцию и не сработало